# Retrieving client area coordinates of a character position from text control

Tags: c++, c, gtk, wxwidgets

I am in need of writing a function which can get screen coordinates from the character position in a text edit control. I am using text edit control provided by `wxWidgets` framework. The `wxTextCtrl` is not exposing any API functions which can provide this information. On Windows, I can get the information by sending [EM_POSFROMCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the text control.

I am wondering how the same can be done on other environments like Linux. For now this needs to be done on only the desktop environments which runs on top of *X Window System* like *GNOME*, *KDE* and *XFCE*. Is there a way to do it? And on these DE, who draws the controls like text edit? Is it managed by X and styled by particular DE?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have tagged this with 'winapi'.  However, it seems to be a question about linux.

Comment: what is the version number of wxWidgets framework you are developing with? Is it 2.8, 2.9 or svn?

Comment: @ezpresso: I am developing on 2.8. But I can upgrade to the latest, even svn version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is possible, but you need to implement a `wxTextCtrl` derived control that relies on underlaying platform capabilities for any particular wxWidgets port (wxMSW, wxGTK, etc).

So, because you have asked about Linux implementation. Let me explain how to implement it for wxGTK 2.9. Below is the `wxTextCtrlExt` control definition:

```
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/gdicmn.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// wxTextCtrlExt
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class wxTextCtrlExt : public wxTextCtrl
{
public:
    wxTextCtrlExt() : wxTextCtrl() { }
    wxTextCtrlExt(wxWindow* parent,
                  wxWindowID id,
                  const wxString& value = wxEmptyString,
                  const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
                  long style = wxTE_MULTILINE,
                  const wxValidator& validator = wxDefaultValidator,
                  const wxString& name = wxTextCtrlNameStr)
    : wxTextCtrl(parent, id, value, pos, size, style, validator, name ) { }

    wxPoint GetPositionCoords(long pos);
};
```

And the wxGTK implementation:

```
#include "wxTextCtrlExt.h"
#include <wx/defs.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

wxPoint wxTextCtrlExt::GetPositionCoords(long pos)
{
    if ( IsMultiLine() ) {
        GtkTextView* txtView = GTK_TEXT_VIEW(m_focusWidget);
        GtkTextBuffer* txtBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(txtView);

        GtkTextIter iter;
        gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(txtBuffer, &iter, pos);

        GdkRectangle location; // output location in buffer coordinates
        gtk_text_view_get_iter_location(txtView, &iter, &location);

        return wxPoint(location.x, location.y);
    }

    return wxPoint(0,0);
}
```

You may also want to convert your buffer coordinates to a widget's ones:

```
    // If we need to convert our coordinates to 
    GdkPoint out;
    gtk_text_view_buffer_to_window_coords(txtView, GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET, location.x, location.y, &out.x, &out.y );

    return wxPoint(out.x, out.y);
```

As you can see, this particular implementation does not account for a single line text entry, that's why you need to use a `wxTE_MULTILINE` style when you are creating the `wxTextCtrlExt` control.

Well, below is how to use it. Let's `m_Text2` be the pointer to a child object of `wxTextCtrlExt` class:

```
long iCharPos = m_Text2->GetInsertionPoint();
long iCharPosMax = m_Text2->GetLastPosition();
wxPoint pos = m_Text2->GetPositionCoords(iCharPos);
```

Now we got our character position coordinates in `pos`. That's it!

Some links that maybe of any interest to you:

- [GtkTextView — Widget that displays a GtkTextBuffer](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextView.html)
- [GtkTextBuffer — Stores attributed text for display in a GtkTextView](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html)

#### Now it is all about your second question.

> And on these DE, who draws the controls like text edit? Is it managed by X and styled by particular DE?

This depends on the wxWidgets port you are using. The wxMSW and wxGTK ports use Win32 and GTK+2 native controls, respectively. The wxUniversal based ports (such as wxX11, wxMGL) draw all the controls by wxWidgets itself. [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) does not mandate the user interface by itself. It provides the basic framework for building GUI environments: drawing and moving windows on the screen and interacting with a mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Excellent answer! I will have to read it in detail to understand it fully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question: How about in KDE? Will this work with KDE? What is the framework KDE uses to draw controls?

Comment: @Appu, Yes, the GTK+ apps work fine in KDE. There is no need for desktop environment to run GTK+ programs. If the required libraries are installed, a GTK+ program can run on top of other X11-based DE or window managers (see ["GTK+"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B)). Also, you may find some of the details on how to make your GTK+ apps look great in KDE [here](http://artipc10.vub.ac.be/wordpress/2009/11/18/making-your-mixed-kde-and-gnome-desktop-look-cool/).

Comment: @Appu, the controls in GTK+ apps are drawn by GTK+ libraries regardless of whether GNOME, KDE or XFCE desktop environment installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which means the code you have provided is sufficient for the DEs which uses X11. For Windows, I will add a different implementation based on `EM_POSFROMCHAR`. Thanks again for the help. I learned a lot from your post and the bounty goes to you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear which character position is sought, but the solution will likely involve [`wxTextCtrl::XYToPosition()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlxytoposition) and/or [`wxTextCtrl::PositionToXY()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlpositiontoxy), but it is unclear which coordinate system the result should be expressed in.

`wxTextCtrl` inherits from `wxWindow` which offers [`wxWindow::GetPosition()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowgetposition).  The parent is found by [`wxWindow::GetParent`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowgetparent).

Between the lot of them, I suspect the answer is easily derived.

Comment: Thanks. But `PositionToXY()` returns row, column position not the screen coordinates. `GetPosition()` won't help as it gives the text control's position not the screen position where caret is. It looks like `wxWidgets` don't expose anything for this problem. This is the reason why I need to see the native API's. On windows, sending the message I have mentioned in my post works really well. I am looking for alternatives on other platforms like GTK.

Comment: So you want what?  The caret position with respect to what?

Comment: I have the caret position. Now I need to get screen coordinates of the position so that I can place another control there. I am building a autocomplete menu which will show up when characters are eneterd to the textbox. A listbox is used to hold the candidates for completion. If I get the screen position, I could just position the listbox there.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since my last wxWidgets experience, but if you can't find an easier (shorter) way, would calculating the extent of the text before the caret (e.g. using wxDC::GetTextExtent()) be a possible approach to finding the position you're after? This would give you a position relative to the start of the text in the wxTextCtrl. You may have to take border sizes and spacing between border and actual text into account. If necessary refine through wxTextCtrl::HitTest()?

BTW What about [wxStyledTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html)?

Comment: `wxStyledTextCtrl` is an option. But it has lot of unnecessary stuff which I may not need. I will take a look at that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a binary search using the `HitTest` function? Not very elegant, but it should be fast, and `HitTest` is implemented for wxGTK2 so it should work.