# Mouse coordinates related to the window

Tags: c, console, mouse, console-application

What is the way I can get the mouse coordinates (especially in rows and columns) related to the active window (assuming 0x0 is the top left corner of the window) ?

Comment: Which OS ? Which framework (if any) ?

Answer (score -2):

This post might suits your needs :

[Get current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423729/get-current-cursor-position)

Note that Win32 offers many useful low level fucntions for C and C++ programmers.

You get the cursor position by calling GetCursorPos.

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
```

This returns the cursor position relative to screen coordinates. Call ScreenToClient to map to window coordinates.

```
if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x and p.y are now relative to hwnd's client area
}
```

You hide and show the cursor with ShowCursor.

```
ShowCursor(FALSE);//hides the cursor
ShowCursor(TRUE);//shows it again
```

You must ensure that every call to hide the cursor is matched by one that shows it again.

Comment: Why do I hide/show the cursor? To obtain position in rows/columns instead, do I divide or there is a particular way?

Comment: It's a copy paste from the link provided, to save you efforts.

The GetCursorPos receive en in/out parameter that points to a struct containing the coordinates of the cursor relative to the screen.
Same apply for ScreenToClient, but now the first parameter is a handler on the window so the function can know what relatives coordinates you want.
What do you mean by "columns" and "lines"?

Comment: colums is the current line character at y and lines is the current character in x.

Comment: Ha ok, sorry I just understand now what you want to achieve.
I can't think of anything simple or practical..

Maybe this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616821/retrieving-client-area-coordinates-of-a-character-position-from-text-control